# React Native TouchableOpacity when I click, change color or Opacity

Tags: react-native, button, touchableopacity, onpress

firstable, I'm korean. I'm not good at eng.
so plz understand me about garmmar or word.

anyway,

now I use TouchableOpacity,
and I want to change the brightness when I push the button like the photo.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv04Q.png)

(I dont need checkmark. just brigtness.)

I'm so glad If you upload the all of code, not part of it.
because I'm begginer, I can't use part of code. sorry.

plz help me... I have been soooo many time in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to utilize an overlay on the image when clicked. So to do this we will do three things.

1. Add TouchableOpacity as a Parent View
2. Add Child Image
3. Add Child Overlay View with 60% Opacity
4. Create overlay Boolean useState()
5. Add Toggle Function to update the overlay value

Full Code for Functional Components

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {
  
  // Variables

  // overlay Boolean useState()
  const [overlay, setOverlay] = useState(false);

  // Functions 
  const toggleOverlay = () => {
    setOverlay(!overlay);
  }

  // Render
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      {/*Parent TouchableOpacity */}
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.parent} onPress={() => toggleOverlay()}>

        {/*Child Image */}
        <Image
          source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300' }}
          style={styles.childImage}
        />

        {/*Child Overlay w/ Conditional Rendering */}
        {overlay && <View style={styles.childOverlay} />}

      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 8,
  },
  parent: {
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  childImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  childOverlay: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor:'black',
    opacity:0.6,
    position:'absolute'
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! it works! you save my life. can you help me more?

Comment: Definitely just ask questions on here and mention me and I'll try to check it every day.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TouchableOpacity
                          activeOpacity={0.8}
                          onPress={() => {
                        
                        
                          }}
                          onPressIn={()=>
                          {
                           this.setState({is_submit_btn_press_in : true})
                          }}
                          onPressOut={() => {
                            this.setState({is_submit_btn_press_in : false})
                          }}
                          style={{
                          
                            flexDirection: 'row',
                            paddingHorizontal: 8,
                            paddingVertical: 8,
                            borderRadius: 5,
                            backgroundColor: this.state.is_submit_btn_press_in ? '#c0c0c0' : '#fe8a0f',
                            borderColor: this.state.is_submit_btn_press_in ? '#c0c0c0' : '#fe8a0f',
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                          
                          }}>
                          <Text
                            style={{
                              textAlign: 'center',
                             
                            
                            }}>
                            Submit
                          </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
```